# Which date format does VarToDateTime(VarDateFromStr) use?

Tags: windows, delphi, ole

I've been having problems lately with date conversion lately. Some workstations my application run on don't convert string to date correctly.

I tracked the issue down to VarDateFromStr that doesn't seem to be checking LOCALE_SSHORTDATE to make the conversion.  I was wondering if anyone knew what it DID check for the conversion. Or does the different behavior only linked to different DLL version?

```
GetLocaleStr(GetThreadLocale, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, 'm/d/yy'); // returns 'dd-MM-yyyy'
FormatDateTime('dd-MM-yyyy', VarToDateTime('05-11-2010')); //returns '11-05-2010'
```

EDIT:
I've been told that changing the short date format (in the control panel) from 'dd-MM-yyyy' to *whatever* and back to 'dd-MM-yyyy' fixed the problem.  I still have to verify this though.

EDIT2: Kindda forgot to mention, the problem has only been confirmed on WinXP SP3 yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ken, the [`VarToDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.VarToDateTime) function internally calls the [`VarDateFromStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/VarUtils.VarDateFromStr)  function wich uses the [`VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/VarUtils_VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT.html) constant to format the date.

to determine wich format contains the `VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT` you can use this code

```
var
 FormatSettings      : TFormatSettings;
begin
      GetLocaleFormatSettings(VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, formatSettings);
      ShowMessage('VarToDateTime is using this format to convert dates  '+formatSettings.ShortDateFormat);
end;
```

now to avoid your problem you can convert your variant value to string and then to datetime using the StrToDateTime function

```
var
v                   : variant;
FormatSettings      : TFormatSettings;
Begin
      v:='05-11-2010';//this is your variant.
      FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='dd-mm-yyyy';//use this format in the conversion
      ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('dd-MM-yyyy', StrToDateTime(V,FormatSettings)));
end;
```

Comment: I'll just add to this since I fell over it. Be sure to set the date separator character too. Otherwise you will fall over in the Netherlands and various other countries.

Comment: Well, VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT's ShortDateFormat is also 'dd-MM-yyyy'. And the problems are not *only* coming from my code, but from DevExpress, TClientDataset, InfoPower...

Comment: Ken, try using the `StrToDateTime` function as is shown in the example.