# What can make VarDateFromStr fail to use the current user's Locale when VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT is supplied as an argument

Tags: windows, delphi, ole

This is a follow-up from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070105/which-date-format-does-vartodatetimevardatefromstr-use).

As asked, what can make VarDateFromStr (from Oleaut32.dll) fail to use the current user's Locale when VAR_LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT is supplied as an argument?

Our app encountered quite a few problems because of this.

On systems with the problem, if we execute the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var V : Variant;
    dte : TDateTime;
begin
  V := Label28.Caption;
  dte := VarAsType(V,varDate) ; //Implicitly calls VarDateFromStr
  V := dte;
  Label28.Caption := V; //Implicitly calls VarBStrFromDate
end;
```

with Label28 starting with a caption of "11-05-2010", the caption will alternate from 11-05-2010 to 05-11-2010 between each calls.

On the given system, GetLocaleStr(GetThreadLocale, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, 'm/d/yy') returns "dd-MM-yyyy" (The short date format for the current user)

The problem happens on WinXP SP3. (Though our application isn't used on any other OS version, can't say if it's specific to that version).

My initial thought is that it might be security-related (the user's security is air-tight), but I couldn't prove it yet.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem with an ADO TParameter.Value (TADODataSet.Parameters.ParamByName().Value).  If you've found a solution, I would greatly appreciate it if you could answer your own question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The likely answer is that the default locale for the user is not a supported lcid for your particular o/s instance.

The work-around is easy - just dont use ugly variants. Try DateTimeToString instead.
P.S. Also helps to specify your version of Delphi.

Comment: If someone looking for an answer could use a Delphi RTL routine to format the date/time, I hope they would not have come to SO to ask the question.  The workaround is not so easy when you're working with library code that uses variants and is calling VarBStrFromDate without you even knowing it.  We're currently having the same problem because ADO (dbGo)'s TParameter.Value is a variant.

Comment: In our case, although TVarData(Value).VType reveals the variant is not a string, the variant date is converted to a string before being assigned to a TDateTime.  The converted string does not match the user's locale, and thus we get a conversion error trying to convert the OleStr to back to a double (TDateTime).  It seems odd that the ideal way to convert a variant date/time value to TDateTime would be to convert it to a string and then back to a double.